# Python 3.x | How to remove brackets and apostrof's in a list to get a cleaner output

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Here is the code so far:

```
dictionary={'i':'prep', 'og':'konj', 'om':'prep', 'som':'subj', 'på':'prep', 'til':'prep', 'en':'determ', 'av':'prep'}
'''Get a list of keys from dictionary which has the given value'''
def getKeysByValue(dictionary, valueToFind):
    listOfKeys = list()
    listOfItems = dictionary.items()
    for item  in listOfItems:
        if item[1] == valueToFind:
            listOfKeys.append(item[0])
    return  listOfKeys

print()
'''Get list of keys with value prep'''
listOfKeys = getKeysByValue(dictionary, 'prep')

prep = 'preposisjoner'
print(f"It is {len(listOfKeys)} {prep} in the dictionary.")
print('They are:')
print()

'''Iterate over the list of keys'''
for key  in listOfKeys:
    print(key,end=', ')

print(), print()

def wrap_by_word(s, n):
    '''returns a string where \\n is inserted between every n words'''
    a = s.split()
    ret = ''
    for i in range(0, len(a), n):
        ret += ' '.join(a[i:i+n]) + '\n'

    return ret

print()
x = wrap_by_word(str(listOfKeys), 2)

print(x)
```

The output I get is this:

It is 5 preposisjoner in the dictionary.
They are:

i, om, på, til, av,

['i', 'om',
'på', 'til',
'av']
**What I want is an output like this:**
i, om
på, til
av
Any help would be highly appreciated.>

Comment: You already know how to print list content without the surrounding list/quotes - the output ``i, om, på, til, av,`` shows as much. What specific problem do you have adjusting that code to the second case?

Comment: But if I just want an output with 2 words on the same row separated by commas... How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the output list you are getting is named as x as mentioned in your code.
Add the following code to your existing code.

```
x = ['i', 'om', 'på', 'til','av']
print(' '.join(x))

# You will get this below as your final output:

 i om på til av
```

Comment: But if I just want an output with 2 words on the same row separated by commas...  How can I achieve that?  Thanks in advance!